# Подключение библиотеки portaudio к Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, аудио

Хочу написать свой синтезатор, почитал про вывод звука в реальном времени. Наткнулся на эту библиотеку, скачал её с официального сайта и не понял, как её подключить в Qt Creator. В сети нашёл подобный способ подключения библиотек для этой IDE:

```
LIBS+="C:\\Libs\Exemple.lib"
```

Но я не нашёл в распакованном архиве с библиотекой файлов с расширением .lib

Пожалуйста, помогите подключить библиотеку portaudio или посоветуйте какую-нибудь другую библиотеку, которая позволит воспроизводить звук "не из файла", так сказать и не из волновых таблиц.

Comment: А какие там файлы?

Comment: Нашёл файлы заголовков .h, есть файлы:
-.m4
-.sh
-.sub
-.guess
-.in
-.cmake
-.developer
-.md
-.am
Есть исходники .cpp, есть файлы решений

Comment: Значит вы скачали исходники, их нужно собрать.

Comment: А что делать, если я не могу их собрать из-за того, что у меня нет библиотек, на которые ссылаются исходники? Просто скачивать да устанавливать библиотеки, до тех пор, пока всё не получится?

Comment: Вот уже кто-то собрал dll - https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сборка, установка ([отсюда](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/wiki/Notes_about_building_PortAudio_with_MinGW)) и линковка в Qt для MinGW.

Должно быть установлено MinGW (я брал из Qt) и MSYS ([инсталлятор под Windows](https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/Installing_MinGW_%26_MSYS_on_Windows))

Сборка и установка:

1. Перейти в папку с дистибом portaudio
2. Запустить Командную строку (cmd.exe)
3. Установить PATH на mingw и msys. Способы:

3.1 В командной строке:

```
  set PATH=<диск>:\<путь к mingw>\bin;<диск>:\<путь к msys>\1.0\bin;%PATH%
```

3.2 Через диалоговое окно в Система -> ... -> переменные окружения Windows. cmd надо будет перезапустить

4. Если переменные подхватились, то станет доступен bash, поэтому в командной строке выполняем bash оболочка запустится и появится bash-3.1$
5. ./configure
6. make

Если все ок, то появятся папки include и lib, которые нужно перенести в соответствующий проект на Qt (можно сделать соответствующий makefile.install).

Линковка к Qt-проекту

Файл pro:

```
...

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/portaudio/include/

# линкуем либу с именем libportaudio.dll.a
LIBS += -L$$PWD/portaudio/lib/.libs -lportaudio.dll 

...
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <portaudio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Pa_Initialize();
    //...
    return ...;
}
```

Проверено, работает!

Comment: Огромное спасибо!